# adding a seekBar into a drawer in android

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, android-seekbar

i have two drawer defined into `activity_main.xml`, that are functional but  i' m not figuring out on how to **add the seekBar into my rightDrawer**, can someone tell me how to do?

my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mDrawerListR;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private String[] drawerItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerListR = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
        mDrawerListR.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItems));
        mDrawerListR.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerListR);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action"/>

</menu>
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize the right drawer view 
Change ListView to LinearLayout

Change

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#123456"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>





public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ListView mDrawerListR;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private LinearLayout rightDrawerLl;

private String[] drawerItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItems));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    rightDrawerLl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer_ll);
    mDrawerListR = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
    mDrawerListR.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItems));
    mDrawerListR.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    findViewById(R.id.seekBar1).setOnTouchListener(seekBarTouchListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(rightDrawerLl);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected OnTouchListener seekBarTouchListener = new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Disallow Drawer to intercept touch events.
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Allow Drawer to intercept touch events.
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        }

        // Handle seekbar touch events.
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
};

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerListR);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
} }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you provide me an example with the activity provided in the question.

Comment: Hi Yokupoku maioku, check in the post added activity class